# Sagemaker Studio is not opening after deleting lifecycle configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I was working on a sagemaker studio for ML work, I attached Lifecycle Configuration with it, which was creating problem. Then I deleted the lifecycle configuration without detaching it, and this problem is happening. Can't start sagemaker studio notebook and this is shown.

[image]

Any suggestion to fix this ?

Comment: As a cheat, you could recreate the configuration with the same name and put a simple echo in it

Comment: Exactly did this and got my case solved. Thanks a lot @GiuseppeLaGualano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably a misunderstanding (or bug) of sagemaker.

As a cheat, you could recreate the configuration with the same name and put a simple echo in it.

For example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "Nothing to do"
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding rePost response here for a way to detach LCC scripts from the domain/user - https://repost.aws/questions/QU91ywEwTsRRqmHKZJ1yVrrA